# Line 105:14: 'accountSelector' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could someone please explain what is going wrong in simple terms so I know how to fix this and can deal with it next time I encounter it.
I have looked through all related questions I could find on stackoverflow and haven't been able to fix it, if I have missed one that answers this then please link it.
I have had this error in the past but usually that was just because I had a typo (e.g. a capital instead of a lowercase) or did not import something correctly however that is not the case this time as far as I can tell.
FIRST CODE app.js
SECOND CODE interactions.js

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import Web3 from 'web3';   
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
// import Token from '../abis/Token.json'
import {
  loadWeb3,
  loadAccount,
  loadToken,
  loadExchange
} from '../store/interactions'

class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {    
    this.loadBlockchainData(this.props.dispatch)
  }
async loadBlockchainData(dispatch) {
    const web3 = loadWeb3(dispatch)
    const network = await web3.eth.net.getNetworkType()
    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId()
    const accounts = await loadAccount(web3, dispatch) // <<--
    const token = loadToken(web3, networkId, dispatch)
    loadExchange(web3, networkId, dispatch)
  }
// ......................

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    account: accountSelector(state)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

```
import Web3 from 'web3'
import {
  web3Loaded,
  web3AccountLoaded,
  tokenLoaded,
  exchangeLoaded
} from './actions'
import Token from '../abis/Token.json'
import Exchange from '../abis/Exchange.json'

export const loadWeb3 = (dispatch) => {
  const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'http://localhost:7545')
  dispatch(web3Loaded(web3))
  return web3
}

export const loadAccount = async (web3, dispatch) => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
  const account = accounts[0]
  dispatch(web3AccountLoaded(account))
  return account
}

export const loadToken = async (web3, networkId, dispatch) => {
    try {
        const token = new web3.eth.Contract(Token.abi, Token.networks[networkId].address)       // new 이거 의존성(버전) 문제 이거 조심!!!!!
        dispatch(tokenLoaded(token))
        return token
    } catch (error) {
        window.alert('Contract not deployed to the current network. Please select another network with Metamask.')
        return null
    }
} 

export const loadExchange = async (web3, networkId, dispatch) => {
  try {
    const exchange = new web3.eth.Contract(Exchange.abi, Exchange.networks[networkId].address)      
    dispatch(exchangeLoaded(exchange))
    return exchange
  } catch (error) {
    window.alert('Contract not deployed to the current network. Please select another network with Metamask.')
    return null
  }
}
```

i don'k now why this happening to me 
but please let me know this problem if you know this issue

Comment: are you sure about this function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    account: accountSelector(state)
  }
} ?  if not then make it function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    account: state.accountSelector
  }
}

Comment: i posted solution if it helped you please vote for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you do not define or import the `accountSelector` function anywhere.

You usually define Redux selector functions in your reducer definition files: they take the current Redux store state as argument (and optionally the connected component props) and return the value to be used in your MapStateToProps object property.
Ex.

```
export const accountSelector = (state) => state.account
```

You can read more about selectors on the [dedicated Redux resources page](https://redux.js.org/introduction/learning-resources#selectors)

Answer (score 0):

*replace this*

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    account: accountSelector(state)
  }
}
```

*with this*

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    account: state.accountSelector
  }
}
```

you are passing complete state in variable instead of accessing.

for your reference, how to access please go through official documentation for your better understanding [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate)

Comment: `accountSelector` seems to be a Redux selector function, so it is ok to call it and passing it the whole store state. The problem here seems to be that `accountSelector` is not defined or imported anywhere.